# Comparison of acidity of aqueous solutions of Lewis Acids

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base

What can be the order of acidity of aqueous solutions of following Lewis acids: $\ce{FeCl3, AlCl3, BeCl2, NiCl2}$

The simplified reactions are:

**$\ce{FeCl3}$**:

$\ce{FeCl3 + 6H2O -> [Fe(H2O)6]^3+(aq) + 3Cl-(aq)}$

$\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^3+(aq) -> [Fe(H2O)5(OH)]^2+(aq) + H+(aq)}$

**$\ce{AlCl3}$**:

$\ce{AlCl3 + 6H2O -> [Al(H2O)6]^3+(aq) + 3Cl-(aq)}$

$\ce{[Al(H2O)6]^3+(aq) -> [Al(H2O)5(OH)]^2+(aq) + H+(aq)}$

**$\ce{BeCl2}$**:

$\ce{BeCl2 + 4H2O -> [Be(H2O)4]^2+(aq) + 2Cl-(aq)}$

$\ce{[Be(H2O)4]^2+(aq) -> [Be(H2O)3(OH)]^+(aq) + H+(aq)}$

**$\ce{NiCl2}$**:

$\ce{NiCl2 + 4H2O -> [Ni(H2O)4]^2+(aq) + 2Cl-(aq)}$

$\ce{[Ni(H2O)4]^2+(aq) -> [Ni(H2O)3(OH)]^+(aq) + H+(aq)}$

For first step of reaction, the octet of $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{Be}$ are not complete. Thus, reaction will be faster in case of $\ce{AlCl3}$ and $\ce{BeCl2}$.

For second step of reaction, the charge density of $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{Fe}$ are more than that in others. Thus, it can break one $\ce{OH}$ bond and the reaction will be faster in case of $\ce{AlCl3}$ and $\ce{FeCl3}$.

But what will be the overall acidity order of these four compounds?

Comment: The charge density order would be : Fe3+>Al3+>Be2+>Ni2+. Practically, so should be the order of Lewis acidic strength. However, the point of octet not being complete is also taken into consideration in many answers on the internet and hence AlCl3 has been deducted as better than FeCl3. However, Ka value of FeCl3 is indeed more than that of AlCl3. I know this doesn't exactly answer the question but adds on some necessary information.

Comment: @HappyFeetMe Can you provide the reference for values of $K_{\text a}$ for $\ce{AlCl3}$ and $\ce{FeCl3}$?